# CSS Button background: 2 solid colors NO gradient

Tags: html, css

trying to build a button (or text box) that looks and works as follow:
Top half button background white or transparent, bottom half of button background solid color. Upon hover the orange should change to blue (hover color I can do).
Color should be behind text. Text should not change color, only the 'bar'.
[the sample button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41rCR.png)

Have tried:

1. Bottom border only (+-10px thick + color), white button background - but cannot seem to set a negative value on the border so that the text are in front of color.
2. Used *Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator* and manipulated the gradient to solid and it worked on the site, but I don't feel that this is sustainable (too much code for a simple function).

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, to get the best answer for your question try to show up your code and what you have tried, so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of a trick available with gradients: specify where the first color ends and where the second color starts. I used `8px` and `9px` to give a simple demonstration. To get the hover effect, override the color in the gradient definition:

```css
button { 
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 8px, orange 9px);
}

button:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 8px, blue 9px);
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: This is not valid - you should not have div elements in a button - W3C validator gives this: Error: Element div not allowed as child of element button in this context.

Comment: I refactored it; now it’s much simpler, and it’s valid HTML code. It’s possible to simulate a sharp gradient specifying the points on which the first color ends and the second color begins. It’s possible to be more precise specifying decimal values, too.

Answer (score 2):

I've used absolute positioned psuedo elements to achieve your desired result

ps:

The `::before` element isn't necessary if you want it transparent but if you want 2 colors you can use it

```css
button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}

button span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

button::before,
button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

button::before {
  top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

button::after {
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}

button:hover::after {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>BUTTON</span>
</button>
```

Comment: This is OK but rather complex - a background-color of linear-gradient(to top, orange 0%, orange 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%) and similarly for hover on the button element is enough.

Comment: @AHaworth you are right although he specificly asked "NO gradient" :)

Comment: Yes, but I suppose it depends on what you mean - there is no gradient in the colors, they are solid.